# jQuery Mobile: Dynamically generated navbar buttons not persisting their active state

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, persistence

I have a very simple jQuery mobile page with a persistent navbar in the header, with buttons that link to "pages" (*data-role="page"* items).

All works well, and the buttons on the navbar highlight as you navigate from page to page.

My issue is that I want to dynamically generate these navbars, on the server side (in PHP). But it seems when you add a navbar using ajax, the *ui-btn-active* and *ui-state-persist* classes don't work properly, and buttons no longer highlight/persist as expected.

Assuming I have a page with a navbar defined within it:

```
<div data-role="page" id="settings" data-theme="a">
```

The simplest example I can demonstrate is replacing content like this:

```
var htmlContent = $("#settings").html();
$("#settings").html(htmlContent);
```

Doing so causes the buttons to no longer persist their active state. It's almost as if the navbar has become "disconnected" from jQuery's awareness and I need to resync up the DOM or something.

It's interesting to note that I don't think the navbar itself is persisting properly either; although it does not transition in and out after replacing the content, page content on the replaced page appears *behind* the navbar (hence all the br's in my sample below).

Man, I hope this makes sense :)

Here's my entire sample... in the head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function loadSomeHTML() {
    var htmlContent = $("#settings").html();
    $("#settings").html(htmlContent); 
}

</script>
```

And here's the content from the body tag:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="welcome" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="TestPersist">
        <div data-theme="" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#schedule" id="navbar_schedule" data-theme="" data-icon="grid" class="navlink">
                        Schedules
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#settings" id="navbar_settings" data-theme="" data-icon="gear" class="navlink">
                        Settings
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="">
        This is the welcome page
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="schedule" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="TestPersist">
        <div data-theme="" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#schedule" id="navbar_schedule" data-theme="" data-icon="grid" class="navlink ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                        Schedules
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#settings" id="navbar_settings" data-theme="" data-icon="gear" class="navlink">
                        Settings
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="">
        This is the sched page
        <input type="button" value="Replace content in settings page" onclick="loadSomeHTML();">
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="settings" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="TestPersist">
        <div data-theme="" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#schedule" id="navbar_schedule" data-theme="" data-icon="grid" class="navlink">
                        Schedules
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#settings" id="navbar_settings" data-theme="" data-icon="gear" class="navlink ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                        Settings
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>This is the settings page
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Well, the lack of response has me concerned that either no one understands the question or my scenario is too unique.

In the meantime, I will include the navbar in each of my page divs... *repeating nearly identical navbar code for each page I am using*... Seems like a step backward from a developmental point of view. But this way the navbar and buttons will persist and work correctly, and I can load dynamic content into the content divs instead of the page divs. Bah.

Answer (score 1):

nah don't make a bunch of headers :)

jqm *is* known to make it hard to dynamically update data attributes, but it's not that bad.

here's a hack in case any one is interested - as long as you are willing to drop the ui-btn-active class and work with themes (which you can of course customize), then you can get this up and running in about 2 minutes.

required reading: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

obviously you need to include yr header template/markup as a static page above yr dynamic content for this to work - i am assuming from your question this is what you want to do, rather than have a php include for non-dynamic content, in which the case the solution would be a more obvious server-side solution.

anywayyys

html markup for sample navbar link

```
<li><a href="javascript:;" id="nav_billing" class="panes" rel="#billing" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="right">Billing Info</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" id="nav_shipping" class="panes" rel="#shipping" data-icon="minus" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right">Shipping Info</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" id="nav_payment" class="panes" rel="#checkout" data-icon="minus" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right">Payment Info</a></li>
```

the important thing here to see is that instead of assigning an active class i.e. ui-btn-active, you'll assign a data-theme to the active class, and just to be sure i am adding data-role="button" to each link as well :)

---

now for the part that's at the end of the doc:

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.button.prototype.options.initSelector = ".panes";
});
```

yup all we're doing here is automatically initializing these buttons so we can use something like this :

```
$('a').buttonMarkup({ theme: "a" });
```

the rest is just putting together the clicker (note the on.click function) :

```
// 100% untested and sure to not work as is 
$(".panes").on('click', function () {

// turn our clicked link into theme b aka active
$(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "b" });

// works nice with icons too
$(this).buttonMarkup({ icon: "check" });

// grab all sibling links and turn them to theme a
// this probably won't work without accounting for the actual markup :)
$(this).siblings().buttonMarkup({ theme: "a" }); 

});
```

Comment: Slick workaround, thanks! Nothing personal, but I am hesitant to mark this as the answer because I think there would still be the issue of the navbar not behaving correctly (content being rendered behind it) but nonetheless I have learned a cool technique that will no doubt come in handy in other areas of development!

Comment: lol no prob.  what do you mean by "content being rendered behind it"?  if yr dynamic content is 'underneath' (on a z-scale) the header, that's more of a markup issue - unrelated to active states of the nav.

Comment: Ordinarily, (and on the initial load of my page) when the navbar is "fixed", it is rendered at the top of the page, and any additional page content is rendered below it (on the y axis). But in my situation, when the page reloads via ajax the navbar kind of floats above the page content, which is rendered underneath the navbar (on the z axis)... that's why I needed to include <br> tags at the top of the page content. It's like the "fixed" attribute only partially works.

Comment: lol a little late - hopefully you've got it going now! - but with my solution there's no need to include the navbar in the ajax call ... youd just call the content in the the container div.  this js would run along side your ajax call, and be applied to the nav above the container div.